# How to turn off Snap automatic background update?

Tags: snap

How do I stop Snap from automatically downloading and applying updates?

The system becomes unresponsive at 100% CPU (according to `top`) and crashes due to Out of Memory (according to `syslog`).

See also here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1861648

So how do I disable Snap automatically downloading and applying updates?

Comment: Are you using a similar setup to the bug report (Ubuntu 20.04 LiveUSB)? Or are your conditions different?

Comment: Is [this reference](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/11/turn-off-automatic-updates-snap-apps/) from the Ubuntu Handbook relevant?